# XML Documentation Navigation for C++ in Visual Studio (as in C#)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, navigation, xml-comments, peek

There is [XML Documentation support for Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/xml-documentation-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) with IntelliSense and all for some time now.

Navigation from XML documentation, peek help etc. does not work though. Coming from C#, I dearly miss those functionalities.
Is there a way to enable this in Visual Studio, maybe via a plugin?

To automatically create XML documentation templates, one can use [CppXmlComments-Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=acmore.CppXmlComments-Generatesxmlcommentsforcprojects).